# Remove unneeded field from DataStore Model causes ProtobufDecodingException

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, android-jetpack-datastore

So I use DataStore with Proto instead of SharedPreferences for my Android app. It works fine:

```
@Keep
@Serializable
data class User(
    val id: Long = -1,
    val someEnum: SomeEnum = SomeEnum.DEFAULT,
    val someParam: Boolean = false,
    val name: String? = null
    ....
)

private const val PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME = "user_preferences.pb"

val Context.userDataStore: DataStore<User> by dataStore(
    fileName = PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME,
    serializer = UserSerializer
)

private object UserSerializer : Serializer<User> {
    override val defaultValue: User
        get() = User()

    override suspend fun readFrom(input: InputStream): User {
        return ProtoBuf.decodeFromByteArray(input.readBytes())
    }

    @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
    override suspend fun writeTo(t: User, output: OutputStream) {
        output.write(ProtoBuf.encodeToByteArray(t))
    }
}
```

If add new fields to object it also works fine.

But if I want to delete some unneeded fields (for example `someParam` from `User` model) then I receive such error:

```
Process: com.example.app, PID: 32229
    kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufDecodingException: Expected wire type 0, but found 2
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufReader.readInt(ProtobufReader.kt:193)
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufDecoder.decodeTaggedInt(ProtobufDecoding.kt:142)
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufDecoder.decodeTaggedEnum(ProtobufDecoding.kt:178)
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufTaggedDecoder.decodeEnum(ProtobufTaggedDecoder.kt:40)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.EnumSerializer.deserialize(Enums.kt:80)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.EnumSerializer.deserialize(Enums.kt:53)
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(ProtobufDecoding.kt:191)
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufTaggedDecoder.decodeNullableSerializableElement(ProtobufTaggedDecoder.kt:91)
        at com.example.app.data.models.User$$serializer.deserialize(User.kt:7)
        at com.example.app.data.models.User$$serializer.deserialize(User.kt:7)
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(ProtobufDecoding.kt:191)
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.internal.ProtobufDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(ProtobufDecoding.kt:181)
        at kotlinx.serialization.protobuf.ProtoBuf.decodeFromByteArray(ProtoBuf.kt:137)
        at com.example.app.data.local.datastore.UserSerializer.readFrom(UserPreferences.kt:34)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readData(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:381)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readDataOrHandleCorruption(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:359)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readAndInit(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:322)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readAndInitOrPropagateFailure(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:311)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.handleRead(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:261)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.access$handleRead(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:76)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invokeSuspend(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:239)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SimpleActor$offer$2.invokeSuspend(SimpleActor.kt:122)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:39)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

So how to handle it correctly? Is there any migration method has to be added in case of deleting fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes to your dataset you'll have to implement a DataMigration scheme which defines how the key-value pairs will change.

I recommend you to check out [Simona Stojanovic's blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/datastore-and-data-migration-fdca806eb1aa).

Comment: can I just reset the data? I tried to add `corruptionHandler = ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler { User() },` but still it throws runtime exception

Comment: found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/76271442/7767664

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer if you need to just reset the data if your model has changed or don't have time for adding migrations logic:

add `CorruptionHandler` when you creating `DataStore`

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesUserDataStore(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    @IODispatcher ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    userSerializer: UserSerializer
): DataStore<User> =
    DataStoreFactory.create(
        serializer = userSerializer,
        scope = CoroutineScope(ioDispatcher + SupervisorJob()),
        corruptionHandler = ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler {
            User()
        },
    ) {
        context.dataStoreFile(USER_DATASTORE_FILE_NAME)
    }
```

throw `CorruptionException` if ProtoBuf fails to decode the data:

```
class UserSerializer @Inject constructor() : Serializer<User> {
    override val defaultValue: User
        get() = User()

    override suspend fun readFrom(input: InputStream): User {
        return try {
            ProtoBuf.decodeFromByteArray(input.readBytes())
        } catch (e: SerializationException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw CorruptionException("The data could not be de-serialized", e)
        }
    }

    @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
    override suspend fun writeTo(t: User, output: OutputStream) {
        output.write(ProtoBuf.encodeToByteArray(t))
    }
}
```